# angularJs view not loading from browser the same code loads view on plunker

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

Here is my plnuker **which loads view as expected on plnkr website**.

[My First Angular SPA](http://plnkr.co/edit/tDKn84?p=preview)

**However, when I downloaded the plunks as a zip and unzipped on my machine and opened index.html it doesn't load the view as expected**. I have looked in to syntax of href and routes as discussed on other related threads.

```
  <body>
   <div ng-app="SmartCartApp">
    <ul>
       <li> <a href="#BaseStationTest">BaseStation Test</a> </li> 
      <li style="float:right"> <a href="#ContactUs">Contact</a> </li>
       </ul>
      <div ng-view=""></div>
   </div>
          <script type="text/ng-template" id="BaseStation.html">  
            <div id="div1">  
                 <br/> {{message}}
            </div>  
        </script>  
       <script type="text/ng-template" id="ContactUs.html">  
            <div id="div2">  
                <br/> {{message}}

            </div>  
        </script> 
     </body>

// create the module and name it smartCartApp
var SmartCartApp = angular.module('SmartCartApp', ['ngRoute']);

// configure our routes
SmartCartApp.config(['$routeProvider', function($routeProvider) {
  $routeProvider 
  .when('/BaseStationTest', {
    templateUrl: 'BaseStation.html',
    controller: 'BaseStationController'
  }) 
    .when('/ContactUs', {
    templateUrl: 'ContactUs.html',
    controller: 'ContactUsController'
  }) 
  .otherwise({
    redirectTo: '/BaseStationTest'
  });
}]);
```

I believe that since this is AngulaJs SPA and which is client framework it doesn't need any backend support (like any webserver to host it). So putting all the html and javaScript in a folder and opening the index.html should open the SPA. Please correct me if this understanding is not right and help me address the issue.

Answer (score 1):

If you open the console, you'd see this error message:

```
Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

You need to run it on a web server. The simplest way to do it is:

1. Download your plunker. Suppose your download location is`/Users/username/Downloads/plunk-tDKn84`
2. Run `cd /Users/username/Downloads/plunk-tDKn84`
3. Run `python -m SimpleHTTPServer`
   This will run a basic HTTP server at port 8000.
4. Open a browser and type `http://localhost:8000/index.html`

You should see your app loading. Hope this helps!

This is how I see it on my localhost:

[image]

Comment: I just checked your message and before that I installed Apache webserver and verified the same. I don't have the privilege to vote yet. I still learned from your post about running python based server which is cool.

Comment: That's okay. you can accept my answer if it worked for you. Glad I could help!